# Path validation - Trying to modify my RegEx so that it only matches paths that include a filename with an extension

Tags: regex, powershell, validation, path

This is what I'm working with: https://regex101.com/r/BertHu/3/

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\|\\?[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)*(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*$
```

The regular expression I'm using is based on [this implementation from Oreilly.](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch08s18.html)

Here's a breakdown (I had to fix some un-escaped characters from Oreilly's expression):

```
(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$\●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$\●-]+)\\|  # Drive
\\?[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)                             # Relative path
(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*                             # Folder
[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*                                    # File
```

I'm implementing this in PowerShell, and the expression will be case-insensitive.

I want to modify this expression such that it only matches paths that contain a file with an extension. I am aware that it's possible for a file to not contain an extension - I don't want to match this edge case.

Examples of what I'd like to happen:

`C:\Applications\Dev\File.txt` Match

`C:\Applications\Dev\` Does not match

`\\192.168.0.1\SHARE\my folder\test.exe` Match

`..\..\bin\my_executable.exe` Match

Etc.

If someone can point me to a solution, that would be of great help!

Thanks much.

### Edit:

After going through all suggestions from everyone I ended up going with the following implementation:

https://github.com/visusys/VSYSUtility/blob/main/Public/Confirm-WindowsPathIsValid.ps1

Maybe some of my fellow PowerShell nerds will find it useful. :)

Comment: why don't you use the built in `fileinfo` object property `.Extension`? this >>> `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Test.Extension)` <<< will return `false` if `$Test` contains a `fileinfo` item that has no extension.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey won't that only work if the file exists? I'm trying to validate correct formatting of the path without checking if it actually exists. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Just trivia, when your regex is parsed to unescape the delimiter, the result is this `^(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\|\\?[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)*(?:[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*$`

Comment: @sln Can you elaborate? I don't really understand what you're referring to, sorry!

Comment: I added the extra \ because the original regex I got from Oreilly threw errors in Regex101: "/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)" 

Did I mess something up?

Comment: No, its just a technicality. The true regex the engine is passed is after parsing regex delimiters. Here this is an example of your raw regex seen using  # delimiter https://regex101.com/r/YnqYsh/1 Its trivial in some ways, but probably important to write raw regex in its base form to save confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by delimiters? What part of my expression is delimited? I'm sorry, I'm not the greatest when it comes to regex. (Which is probably apparent by now)

Comment: @Jay - ah! i did not catch that. [*blush*] however, if you are using PoSh already ... why don't you literally check for the file? as long as you have a connection to the filesystem in question, that would seem more direct & robust.

Comment: @Jay - here's a different way to check for "last part has a dot in it". presuming that `$InStuff` contains the sample lines in your 1st link, this >>> `$InStuff.Where({$_.Split('\')[-1] -match '\.'})` <<< gives the 3 lines that end with `somethingDOTsomething`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I ended up going with this implementation: 

https://github.com/visusys/VSYSUtility/blob/main/Public/Confirm-WindowsPathIsValid.ps1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pragmatic solution is to apply your validating regex first and - if a path matches - call the [`System.IO.Path.GetExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.GetExtension) .NET API method on it:<sup>[1]</sup>

- Note: I haven't looked at the specifics, but your regex also matches malformed paths such as `C:\foo\C:\bar` - [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69950575/45375).

```sh
'C:\Applications\Dev\File.txt',
'C:\Applications\Dev\',
'\\192.168.0.1\SHARE\my folder\test.exe',
'..\..\bin\my_executable.exe',
'invalid:path' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $valid = $_ -match '^(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\|\\?[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)*(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*$'
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Path = $_
      Valid = $valid
      HasExtension = if ($valid) { '' -ne [IO.Path]::GetExtension($_) }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Path                                   Valid HasExtension
----                                   ----- ------------
C:\Applications\Dev\File.txt            True         True
C:\Applications\Dev\                    True        False
\\192.168.0.1\SHARE\my folder\test.exe  True         True
..\..\bin\my_executable.exe             True         True
invalid:path                           False
```

---

<sup>[1] On Windows, this method itself performs *limited* validation: paths with *illegal characters* such as `"` cause an exception, but not *malformed* ones. On Unix-like platforms, where the file systems typically allow *any* character in paths except `NUL`, no validation appears to be performed at all (even `NUL` characters don't cause an exception).</sup>